# I make 25% of three pointers, if I shoots 10 of them, what is the probability that I will have made exactly 5.

Tags: probability

I thought about doing $(0.25^5)+(0.75^5)$, not sure if this indicates that I makes $5$ in row and then miss $5$ in a row or if it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's not $+$ it's $\times$
Second you need to account for all the ways it could happen which is $10\choose 5$.

So the answer is $ {10\choose 5} \times .25^5 \times .75^5$